# COUNTIF then Compare 2 columns if they are not equal bring back the number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

Working on an analysis and I have just hit a brain fart on the very last piece of it. I have a data set where I need if the part is Valid ("YES") in column X then I need it to compare columns V:W, if the numbers in the cells are not equal then return the number count that are not equal.

I tried

```
=COUNTIFS(Export!X:X,"YES",IF(SUM(Export!V8:V10000<>Export!W8<>W10000,1,0))
```

I realize that doesn't work, but maybe you get the jist. The second IF function worked perfect as an array until I was hit with needing it to only count the Valids.

[image]

Comment: some more detail would be helpful. Maybe some dummy data?

Comment: and what should the answer be?

Comment: `return the number count that are not equal`... Could you explain this?

Answer (score 0):

Here

=SUMPRODUCT(--(Export!X8:X10000="YES"),--(Export!V8:V10000<>Export!W8:W10000))

Comment: I don't think that's working correctly... the number returned isn't correct.

Comment: If column X says YES, sum the number of in V <> W

Answer (score 0):

If not correct solution

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Export!X8:X10000="YES"),--(Export!V8:V10000<>Export!W8:W10000))
```

Then write expected result based on the picture.

[image: See picture]

Comment: Yeah this should work, but it's bringing back the wrong count. fml. but be something else inside the sheet

Comment: Check your data. Test it with formula =V2<>W2 then find out where is unexpected outcome.